# How to visualise the results on grafana with cpu- memory usage metrics?

Tags: kubernetes, memory, prometheus, grafana, cpu-usage

How can I graph cpu and memory utilisation from prometheus on grafana?

I need to evaluate graphs based on these two metrics above,
Where can I put this on grafana? Is it as a query?

I need to know how it works - any help with videos or articles?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to consider what specific metrics you want to display. Prometheus supports many of them:

- Kubernetes Container CPU and Memory Usage
- Kubernetes Pod CPU and Memory Usage
- Kubernetes Node CPU and Memory Usage
- Kubernetes Namespace CPU and Memory Usage
- Kubernetes Cluster CPU and Memory Usage
- Kubernetes Container CPU and Memory Requests
- Kubernetes Pod CPU and Memory Requests
- Kubernetes Node CPU and Memory Requests
- Kubernetes Namespace CPU and Memory Requests
- Kubernetes Cluster CPU and Memory Requests
- Kubernetes Container CPU and Memory Limits
- Kubernetes Pod CPU and Memory Limits
- Kubernetes Node CPU and Memory Limits
- Kubernetes Namespace CPU and Memory Limits
- Kubernetes Cluster CPU and Memory Limits
- Kubernetes Resource Capacity
- Kubernetes CPU and Memory Request Commitment (Resource Requests vs Capacity)
- Kubernetes CPU and Memory Limit Commitment (Resource Limits vs Capacity)
- Kubernetes Resource Utilization (Resource Usage vs Capacity)
- Kubernetes Resource Saturation

You can read about all these metrics, as well as the monitoring by prometheus itself, [here](https://www.replex.io/blog/kubernetes-in-production-the-ultimate-guide-to-monitoring-resource-metrics).
Once the prometheus collects and processes the appropriate metrics, you can take care of Grafana. You have to install it via Helm, for example, and then set `port-forwarding` to the appropriate pod. Then you will need to authenticate. When it comes to displaying Prometheus data, you need to create a new dashboard and then add a variable for Prometheus. Everything is fully described in [this guide](https://www.replex.io/blog/kubernetes-in-production-the-ultimate-guide-to-monitoring-resource-metrics-with-grafana). You will find each step described, also with screenshots.